# how to create generic java class that extends class and implements interface?

Tags: java, android, interface, type-parameter

i am using DDD in my android project structure, in some domains, i need to create a new folder named "behavior" to put all screen behavior in this folder, like so "public class profileBehavior { .. }"

project print: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=r1hppi&s=8#.VPDdSlPF_rc

with the passage of time and the improvement aiming reuse, I'm thinking of creating a "genericBehavior" with the common methods instead, something like:

```
public class GenericBehavior {

private static Context context;
private static View view;

public GenericBehavior(Context context) {
    context = context;
}
public GenericBehavior(View view) {
    view = view;
}

public static GenericBehavior with(final Context context) {


    return new GenericBehavior(context);
}

public GenericBehavior where(final View view) {
    return new GenericBehavior(view);
}
```

and in the profileBehavior class, i hope to reuse the **with** and **where** methods to set a profileBehavior context and view

like:

```
public class ProfileBehavior extends GenericBehavior {


public ProfileBehavior(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
```

and in the profileFragment i hope to use like:

```
ProfileBehavior
            .with(getActivity())
            .where(rootView)
            .listenAttachOptions()
            .doScrollStuff();
```

I reading about the type params and interfaces, but i realy confused about that. in my case, its better to duplicate methods in behaviors or have a solutions for this?

Comment: Your question is not clear: "or have a solutions for this?" what do you mean by that?

Comment: i hope to use my profileBehavior with chaining like "classBehavior.whit(x).where(x).foo().bar().baz()....;" but the way i do, it's not possible.  to do this, I have to have all methods in generic class or separate calls: "classBehavior.whit(x).where(x); classBehavior.x(); classBehavior.y();"

Comment: I do not want to duplicate the methods (with and where) in all behaviors;

Comment: example of what I hope: Picasso.with(getActivity).load(url).into(ImagView);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three ways (that I could think of) doing it:

1. by creating a base class (can be abstract) and implement `where()` and `with()` in this base class and extend it.
2. If you're using Java 8 you get [default methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) (you *can* have a default implementation of methods in an interface)
3. [Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance): you can create an object that implements `where()` and `with()` (a behavior "base" object) and have any other instance of a "behavior" class hold an instance of such base-object as a private member. Each such class will delegate every `where()` and `with()` calls to this base-object.

An example of implementation of #3:

```
class BaseBehavior implement Behavior {
    public Behavior with(final Context context) {
        return new BaseBehavior(context);
    }

    public Behavior where(final View view) {
        return new BaseBehavior(view);
    }
}

class AnotherBehavior implement Behavior {
    BaseBehavior base;    

    AnotherBehavior(BaseBehavior base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    public Behavior with(final Context context) {
        return base.with(context);
    }

    public Behavior where(final View view) {
        return base.with(view);
    }        
}
```

In general, composition is preferred over inheritance (so if you're not using Java 8 - it's better to go with #3 than with #1) because of many reasons, if to name a few: easier to debug and maintain, the code becomes less decoupled and has a simpler hierarchy and you can inherit (extend) only one class.

Comment: Java 8 is not available on Android.

Comment: @XaverKapeller so #2 is out of the question :)

Comment: I think I did not understand, the way I do, I put the methods with and where in all classBehavior, I wanted to baseBehavior was just not have them in every classBehavior but extend baseBehavior for it. which generated the problem is that with have to return a context for own class and not for the baseBehavior, so I was reading about type params and interfaces. sorry for my english.

Comment: If you're doing inheritance, make sure to pass the `context` in the constructor to the parent (base-class) using `super(context)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that, though you would want modify or append instance variables not replace static ones, and return `this` not a new instance or at least an instance that wraps the old one `return new GenericBehavior(context, this);` ... GenericBehavior should probably be an interface ProfileBehavior implements so you can have ProfileBehavior extend some other class you want to act on.

Comment: the question is: how i remove methods (where and with "common in all classBehaviors") and put in genericBehavior class or inteface factory and use chaining? how to create a interface with this? So I do not understand.

Comment: you should really try one thing at a time, first learn to function chain by returning 'this', then learn to use 'implements' or extends as needed. maybe you do want ProfileBehavior to extend GenericBehavior, that will work, so long as you don't need to wrap other classes.